# TFX. Properties for CsvCoder in CsvExampleGen: 'Columns do not match specified csv headers'

Tags: python, tensorflow, tfx

I am working with TensorFlow Extended and stack in a loading .csv file.
This file has `;` separation and can't be read by default TFX generator `CsvExampleGen()`. It throws out the following error: `ValueError: Columns do not match specified csv headers`

I found that this problem related to inner dependencies such as `tft.coders.CsvCoder()` that requires not default parameters to parse .csv file.

Question is the following:

- How to throw parameters in `tft.coders.CsvCoder()` from `tfx.components.CsvExampleGen`?

```
from tfx.components import CsvExampleGen
from tfx.utils.dsl_utils import external_input

data_path = './data'
intro_component = CsvExampleGen(input=external_input(data_path))
...
```

Comment: Current solution is to transform the datafile with pandas:
`df = pd.read_csv(_file_path, sep=';') df.to_csv(_file_path)`

Answer (score 1):

From the comments

> Current solution is to transform the datafile with pandas:
>
> `df = pd.read_csv(_file_path, sep=';')`

> `df.to_csv(_file_path)`
>
> (paraphrased from Oleks).